# xcodebuild Archive failed but xcarchive created

Tags: ios, archive, xcodebuild, on-demand-resources

I recently started using On demand resources in my project.To support it i changed my build script so that now i first create an archive and then export it to ipa.
Here are the commands i am using 
    xcodebuild -project ABC.xcodeproj/ -configuration Debug -scheme "ABC" archive -archivePath bin/debug/ABC.xcarchive
    xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath bin/debug/ABC.xcarchive -exportPath bin/debug -exportOptionsPlist ABC/content/Info_debug.plist

When i execute first command build runs smoothly but in the end it shows

CreateAssetPackManifestPlist

Creating AssetPackManifest.plist

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

There are no error logs or any other indication which show any problem. Even though it shows archive failed xcarchive file is created and i am able to use it to successfully export to ipa. I also installed and validated the ipa , app runs fine.
So i modified command to
xcodebuild -project AMC.xcodeproj/ -configuration Debug -scheme "ABC" archive -archivePath bin/debug/ABC.xcarchive || exit 0
Now everything is working fine but i am still unsure why command shows "Archive failed". What can be the reasons for it and is it ok to export it to ipa even though it shows archive failed.

Comment: hey, I am too getting this behaviour, any updates??